# What's the deprecation policy of previous releases of Mono?

Tags: mono

Mono 3.0 has been **[released in October 2012](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2012/Oct-22.html)**. Latest version (v3.0.12) **[has been released in June 2013](http://news.mono-project.com/2013/06/19/new-mono-releases/)**.

In his **"What is new in Mono?"** presentation at MonkeySpace 2013, Miguel de Icaza **[states that "Mono 2.10.X is no longer supported"](http://www.slideshare.net/migueldeicaza/monkey-space-2013/4)**.

Despite all my researchs, I haven't been able to find an authoritative source regarding Mono support policy and scheduled deprecation of a version.

Is there an updated web page similar to the **[Microsoft products lifecycle fact sheet](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/products/lifecycle)**  for Mono?

That would be handy in order to plan Mono upgrades or check if it's worth reporting a bug for a specific version.

Comment: Only Xamarin can provide you an answer I think, as it provides commercial support for Mono. Any Mono support contract provider can set its own policy, as Mono is open source, so I don't think there will be a single lifecycle policy to govern all parties.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks. I'll try to contact them and will post some feedback.

Comment: @LexLi Your feedback made me realized that the title of the question was poorly worded and misleading. I'm not looking for commercial support, but rather some information about the deprecation policy of previous Mono releases. I'll update the question accordingly.